# deleted folder under svn control, replaced with folder of same name with different content, now svn wont work!

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have recently upgraded one of our systems from Code Igniter 1.7.2 to 2.0.1.

Do do this you are required to replaced the *system* directory with a newer version.

The old CI system was under version control, including the *system* directory.

When I go to commit I get
[image: Please execute the cleanup command]

So I go to execute the cleanup command and I get [image: system is not a working copy directory]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup the new system directory somewhere else (outside of the SVN working copy), revert the working copy to its old state (or even do a fresh checkout if needed), delete the system folder and commit, then copy the backed up system folder into the working copy, add it to SVN and commit again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just deleted the system folder (without `svn remove` to let subversion know) and replaced it with some other content, you could first bring back the last committed version of it and then replace or update the content with svn.

Example: Backup and remove the current system folder, do a `svn update` in "tada", "system" comes back. Now either `svn remove` it to `svn add` and commit the newer files or copy the new ones over it and commit the changes.